# Add fixtures to Jasmine without using jquery-jasmine. Is it possible?

Tags: jquery, html, jasmine

I've recently moved from jQuery to min.js for a mobile web app and the Jasmine tests are now failing. Previously, all fixtures would be loaded using jquery-jasmine but now I'm only left with min.js and pure js.

Is there a way to load HTML fixtures without jquery-jasmine, i.e. does jasmine support direct injection of HTML somehow or are there any other libraries that do that?

I did have a search and could not find any. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I tried to do `document.body.innerHTML = '<fixture ...>'` but that didn't work

Answer (score 0):

i was in the same boat as well. This may not be the best solution for using HTML fixtures with vanilla Javascript but a start.

Using http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/index.html as your test runner, install https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-html2js-preprocessor and follow the instructions to config it in your karma config file.
This plugin transforms your HTML files to Javascript where its stored in the **__html__**["myFixture.html"] variable. When accessing the variable in your Jasmine tests, be sure to include the complete path from where your karma config file's base path is located. From there you can apply it anywhere in the DOM variable from the document.body.innerHTML and document.body.outerHTML properties, to beyond.

This solution worked for me when i needed to test a javascript module that manipulates css classnames and html tags via the DOM.

I used two different fixtures with no major testing issues across all major browsers. The minor source of problems was with IE 11 and 10 (no surprise there) as it does not allow the modification of the document.body.outerHTML variable. I had to take out the afterEach functions (which set document.body.outerHTML = "";) out of the tests for them to pass on IE. Not a big loss but more of an unnecessary redundancy as the DOM is replaced by the loaded fixture in the beforeEach function.

Hope this is helpful.

Michael